# "Two-way binding" between child components in Angular 2

Tags: angular, data-binding, binding

I have this situation.

Child A holds a list of items with their properties (let's asume Title)
Whenever an item title in Child A is changed it should be added/updated to Child B
Whenever an item in Child B is edited it should be updated in Child A
Whenever an item in Child B is removed, the value in Child A should be set to default(we can keep the default one easily)

I went trough the Component Communication doc at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service
and tried to implement the communication trough a microservice and store the values in the parent component. But I realised data inconsistency is possible since we will use Observables.

Could you propose a way or pattern for "two-way" bindings between child components?

[image: Components]

Comment: You could bind to a shared service and update something in the service. That would be an easy way to do it.

Comment: I put reference to this way: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: What kind of 'data inconsistency' are you talking about?